# How can I caption an enumerated list?

Tags: captions, enumerate, itemize

When I have a list such as

```
\begin{enumerate}
% List contents here...
\end{enumerate}
```

Or

```
\begin{itemize}
% List contents here...
\end{itemize}
```

How can I caption it, eg. as "List 1.1"? I could put it inside a table environment, but then the caption would say "Table 1.1", and this isn't a table.

Comment: do you want the environment to float?

Comment: @cmhughes No, but I'd prefer to have an answer for either option.

Comment: ok, I'll update my answer later today

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a non-floating example at the end

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one way that you can do it using the [`newfloat`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/newfloat) package.

Notice that it is completely compatible with the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) and [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) package, and that it provides the command

```
\listofmyfloats
```

to give a list of your floats.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=cmh,placement={!ht},name=List]{myfloat}

\captionsetup[myfloat]{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newenvironment{listenv}[1]
    {\begin{myfloat}[tb]
      \begin{enumerate}
    \caption{#1}
    }
    {\end{enumerate}\end{myfloat}
    }

\begin{document}

\listofmyfloats
\begin{listenv}{More details}\label{list1}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{listenv}

See list \ref{list1} or figure \ref{fig1}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{A real figure}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you want a non-floating version, you can tweak this to, for example,

```
\newenvironment{nonfloatlistenv}[1]{%
    \center
    \captionof{myfloat}{#1}
    \enumerate
}
{\endenumerate\endcenter}
```

and then

```
\begin{nonfloatlistenv}{Non floating}\label{list1}
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{nonfloatlistenv}
```

Tweak this how you see fit.

Comment: The demonstration looks quite complex, could you please explain the different parts and add some comments?

Comment: Also, this labels my lists incorrectly. I expect my lists in `section` n to be labeled List n.1, List n.2, and so on. Your MWE labels it `List 1` no matter how many sections I add.

Comment: @Superbest sounds like you want to use the `\numberwithin` command